# what is the time complexity of a nested for loop that iterates n - 1 - i?

Tags: time-complexity

So if I have a loop like this?

```
int x, y, z;
for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++){
        x = 1;
        y = 2;
        z = 3;
    }
}
```

so we start with the x, y, z definition so we have 4 operations there, 
`int i = 0` occurs once, `i < n - 1` and `i++` iterate `n - 1` times, `int j = 0,` iterates `n - 1` times and `j < n - 1 - i` and `j++` iterates `(n - 1) * (n - 1 - i)` and `xyz = 1` would iterate `(n - 1) * (n - 1 - i)` as well. So if I were to simplify this, would the above code run at `O(n^2)?`

Answer (score 1):

> so we start with the x, y, z definition so we have 4 operations there

This is not necessary, we need only count critical operations (i.e. in this case how often the loop body executes).

> So if I were to simplify this, would the above code run at O(n²)?

A function `T(n)` is in `O(g(n))` if `T(n) <= c*g(n)` (under the assumption `n >= n0`) for some constants `c > 0`, `n0 > 0`.

So for your code, the loop body is executed `n - i` times for every `i`, of which there are `n`. So we have:

[image]

Which is indeed true for `c = 1/2`, `n0 = 1`. Therefore `T(n) ∈ O(n²)`.

Comment: then to add to my above question, if I had an if statement above the loop, if user input == value, then I call a O(n^2) function. Would the function still be O(n^2) complexity since I would have the function and the nested loop would it still be O(n^2) wouldn't that mean the efficiency remains the same despite the extra function?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes. 2 * O(n^2) = O(n^2). Intuitively speaking, we ignore constant factors in asymptotic notation.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the complexity is O(n^2). There is more than one way to approach the question of why.

The formal way is to count the number of iterations of the inner loop, which will be n-1 the first time, then n-2, then n-3, ... all the way down to 1, giving a total of n*(n-1)/2 iterations, which is O(n^2).

An informal way is to say the outer loop runs O(n) times, and "on average", `i` is roughly n/2, so the inner loop runs on average about (n - n/2) = n/2 times, which is also O(n). So the total number of iterations is O(n) * O(n) = O(n^2).

With both of these techniques, it's not enough to just say that the loop body iterates O(n^2) times - we also need to check the complexity of the inner loop body. In this code, the body of the inner loop just does a few assignments, so it has a complexity of O(1). This means the overall complexity of the code is O(n^2) * O(1) = O(n^2). If instead the inner loop body did e.g. a binary search over an array of length n, then that would be O(log n) and the overall complexity of the code would be O(n^2 log n), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you are right. Time complexity of this program will be O(n^2) at its worst case.